# Tmux rename window to current directory

Tags: shell, tmux

So I have this function in my `.zshrc` to rename my current tmux window to the current directory.

```
precmd () {
    tmux set-window-option -qg window-status-format "#[fg=colour18 bg=colour18] | #[fg=white, bg=colour18] #I | ${PWD##/*/} #[fg=colour18, bg=colour18] | "
    tmux set-window-option -qg window-status-current-format "#[fg=colour18, bg=blue] | #[fg=white, bg=blue] #I | ${PWD##/*/} #[fg=blue, bg=colour18] | "
}
```

And this works fine, but I'm wondering why the same code won't work in my `.tmux.conf`

```
# Status Bar
set-window-option -qg window-status-format "#[fg=colour18 bg=colour18] | #[fg=white, bg=colour18] #I | ${PWD##/*/} #[fg=colour18, bg=colour18] | "

set-window-option -qg window-status-current-format "#[fg=colour18, bg=blue] | #[fg=white, bg=blue] #I | ${PWD##/*/} #[fg=blue, bg=colour18] | "
```

If I try to use this, I get a error when I start up tmux.
Any reason for this? Can I get the same effect using `#{pane_current_path}"` and shorten the path to just the current directory?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting in tmux...?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mhartington/6f4e89503785acb326be

`invalid or unknown command`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not working because the function is executed before the tty's are created. It works with the shell function because you execute this after tmux is completely started. But the `.tmux.conf` is executed during the startup of tmux.

So I would just keep it in your `.zshrc`, possibly executing the function right away.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no easy way to achieve that for the time being. In addition to what @rednaw has said, there is another important factor which makes it impossible.

tmux supports the syntax of "#(shell-command)". Therefore, it might be tempting for you to

```
tmux set-window-option window-status-format "#(echo ${PWD##/*/})"
```

However, this line won't work as you would expect. The tricky thing is: the "PWD" is that of current session not the PWD of current pane.

Comment: Thanks, that was I was starting to think.

Comment: You can use this instead shell command instead `#(tmux_pwd="#{pane_current_path}"; echo "${tmux_pwd//*\//}")` - just added as another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although shell commands are run in the working directory of the session (instead of the window or pane), so you can't use `$PWD`, you can still obtain the pane's working path from within that command using `#{pane_current_path}`, and then shorten that to just the last part of the path using a shell command, e.g. I have this in my tmux config:

```
tmux_conf_theme_window_status_format='#I #(tmux_pwd="#{pane_current_path}"; echo "${tmux_pwd//*\//}"): #W'
tmux_conf_theme_window_status_current_format='(#I) #(tmux_pwd="#{pane_current_path}"; echo "${tmux_pwd//*\//}"): #W'
```